# I don't understand why my function is not working

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I have a read function to check whether someone should go and use the write `MakeEligible` function. Here is the code:

```
function ShouldIMakeMyselfEligible(address) public view returns (bool) {
    if (_RestrictedFromDividend[address(msg.sender)]) {
        if (now >= (ClaimTime[address(msg.sender)] + 10 minutes)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
     } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have tested that yes, the address is `_RestrictedFromDividend`, and also if they claim before 10 minutes has passed in the following function:

```
function MakeEligible(address) public {
    if (now >= (ClaimTime[address(msg.sender)] + 10 minutes)) {
        _RestrictedFromDividend[address(msg.sender)] = false;
    } else {
        _RestrictedFromDividend[address(msg.sender)] = true;
    }
}
```

Nothing will happen and they will remain `_RestrictedFromDividend`, which is what I want to happen. Once 10 minutes has passed, even though `ShouldIMakeMyselfEligible` will return false, using the `MakeEligible` command will successfully make the `_RestrictedFromDividend` go away. So I know that the `ClaimTime` is updating and calculating correctly but in the first function something has gone wrong. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

In `ShouldIMakeMyselfEligible` you are performing checks against `msg.sender`, which is used to access the calling address in a **transaction**. However, this function is marked as `view` and so is accessed via a **call** rather than a transaction. `msg.sender` likely does not contain the data you expect it to.

You specify that an address should be given as an input to `ShouldIMakeMyselfEligible`, however you do not name this variable. My guess is that you are unclear on the use of function inputs and `msg.sender`, and your intention was that the user supplies their address when calling `ShouldIMakeMyselfEligible`. In that case, you should instead give a name to the inputted address and perform the checks against this named variable:

```
function ShouldIMakeMyselfEligible(address _addr) public view returns (bool) {
    if (
        _RestrictedFromDividend[_addr] &&
        now >= (ClaimTime[_addr] + 10 minutes)
    ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your second function is accessed via a transaction and so `msg.sender` is being used correctly. However, there is no need to include an address in the function inputs. And you do not need to wrap `msg.sender` in `address()` - it already is an address.

```
function MakeEligible() public {
    if (now >= (ClaimTime[msg.sender] + 10 minutes)) {
        _RestrictedFromDividend[msg.sender] = false;
    } else {
        _RestrictedFromDividend[msg.sender] = true;
    }
}
```